# Using AOP with Guice 3 to redefine a `new Socket()` to `new Bar()` in third-party code?

Tags: java, aop, guice

I have a situation with a newly Guicified application using a vendor provided network communications library written a long, long time ago, which I now need to be able to go through a ssh-provided SOCKS5 proxy, and it works well with the system property "-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1" in a stand-alone application.

Unfortunately this needs to run in a situation where this influences other things, so I was wondering if I could use the AOP lurking inside Guice 3 to catch the calls to `new Socket` inside either a specific class and/or in all classes in said library and forward them to my own class which then creates a proxied instance instead?

Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with what AOP actually *can* do, and whether this is a good idea at all.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

AOP in Guice only works for objects that Guice creates for you (so *nothing* for which `new X()` is written, in your code or a library's). It also can only intercept method calls (not constructor calls) and is primarily useful for doing something before and/or after a method call rather than trying to change the method call completely.

Comment: Ok.  Can you recommend another toolset that allows me to do what I need to do?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: While something may exist, I don't know of anything that allows you to change a constructor call into something totally different. To my knowledge, constructor calls are one of the most unchangeable things in Java.